# Upgrading to an SSD with a fresh windows install

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, ssd

So I am after upgrading my PC that i have had a while now to using an SSD with a fresh copy of windows that I own. My question is that after installing it, changing the BIOS settings ect. Am I going to run into any problems with there being a copy of windows on my HDD because my HDD has all of my data on it right now that I am after keeping, along with my programs that i would prefer not to have to sit and install again.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you can't run apps from a boot drive you are not booted into, not in as simple a way as you are considering. The best way would be to clone the original drive to the SSD, then [after full testing] erase the old drive.

Samsung SSD's come with a utility to clone your old drive to the new SSD [though it's not always successful]. I can only assume others are likely to come with similar software.

Essentially, the safe way is you start with your existing drive in the machine & the new SSD in a USB enclosure, clone, then swap in the new SSD; remove the original HD, keep it for a while, make sure everything works as planned.

My Samsung clone failed & I ended up using [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/en-gb/personal/pc-backup/), not free, but the trial version might allow you to do it.

It would definitely be worth preparing for both alternatives before starting out; make a boot USB stick for Windows & Acronis, in case of failure.

Your apps etc will then be correctly installed on your new drive & you can wipe the old one [after a week or so of testing, just in case] then use it as backup or data storage.

Mine needed Windows re-certifying as Genuine, but I just clicked through the links & it worked.